# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value'with value '@string/facebook_app_id')

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to add facebook to my app and I'm following these steps exactly as they tell me (I'm doing the Eclipse Setup):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started?locale=es_LA#eclipse

But I get an error on my AndroidManifest.xml on this line:

```
<meta-data android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
```

The error says: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value'with value '@string/facebook_app_id')

Comment: does facebook_app_id exists in your string.xml

Comment: You should add the facebook_app_id in your string.xml file.

Comment: @MoubeenFarooqWarar It's added just like the tutorial shows on the image. <string name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId">@string/facebook_app_id</string>

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In values/string.xml add this line (between the resource tags)

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">Facebook</string>
```

Comment: The error is fixed, thanks... It's strange that they have it like that in the tutorial. I wonder if everybody gets the same error.

Comment: Actually android tutorials usually start with explaining these files. Maybe you wanted to go too fast. Just remember that @string is referring to a variable in that file. :)

Answer (score 5):

goto -> **res->values->string.xml** open that file and write

```
 <string name="facebook_app_id">Facebook</string>
```

Comment: Someone else got ahead of your answer for just a few minutes :P

Comment: no prob but see my comment i was the first to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).